# print result in windows form applications in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Suppose I have two arrays a[] and b[], Array a[25] and b[25] both have 25 values, now see the following code:-

```
for(int i=0;i<25<i++)
{    
 for(int j=0;j<25;j++)
 {   
     if(a[i]==a[j])
     {            
           count++;
     }
     else
          continue;
}
//print the result of each comparison

}
```

In the above code i am comparing each value of a[] with  all values of b[] and counting the occurrences . But I am not getting how the show(print) the occurrrences of each comparison in windows form applications

Comment: @SamLeach, No. they have 25 values.

Comment: you have an error, you are checking for equality of a and a arrays 'if(a[i]==a[j])' instead of 'if(a[i]==b[j])'

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Textbox` and set it to multiline and scrollable:

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;
textBox1.Width = 150;
textBox1.Height = 80;  
textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;

textBox1.Text = "Occurrences: " + count.ToString(); // print count
```

Answer (score 0):

In project settings set application type as Console. Then you will get console and form.

OR

You can use console window to do that as well,Just add following line into your form application and then use  `Console.WriteLine`.then it open with console as well.

```
     public Form1()
     {
       AllocConsole();
       InitializeComponent();
     }

      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
      private static extern bool AllocConsole();

    void PrintMethod()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Occurence :"+count.ToString());
    }
```

||

easily you can use `listBox` to display the result.

```
    void PrintMethod()
    {
      listBox1.Items.Add("Occurence :"+count.ToString());
    }
```

**updated:**

you can use  `Console.ReadKey();` to hold the pointer and then hit enter button you can continue.

exsample :

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test"+i);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: I have more than lakh outputs that are shown continuously without a pause and I am unable to observe those outputs, is there any command so that Console shows output slowly and I can observe the output values

Comment: Then better to write out put into text file

Comment: If it helped you to solve your problem mark it as answer. It will help other community users to find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code :

```
   textBox1.Multiline = true;
```

To show he count for each comparison try to add += for  `textBox1.Text`

```
textBox1.Text += Enviornment.NewLine+ "Occurrences: " + count.ToString(); // print count here
```